# Regular expression issue for a custom pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Below is the pattern example:

AB17-12345

So the first 2 characters are alpha characters and 3rd and 4th are digits followed by a "dash" character then followed by 5 digits.

This is what i have now:

```
"/[^A-Z]{2}\d{5}/"
```

It will be very helpful if someone can help me out with this as i am just a starter in regular expressions.

Comment: `/[^A-Z]{2}\d{2}-\d{5}/`

Comment: @bassxzero not A-Z? `^` inside `[ ]` is not isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

[`^[A-Z]{2}\d{2}-\d{5}$`](https://regex101.com/r/PrQG7L/2)

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Match 2 uppercase characters `[A-Z]{2}`
- Match 2 digits `\d{2}`
- Match a dash `-`
- Match 5 integers `\d{5}`
- The end of the string `$`

Comment: Can also use `[[:upper:]]` or `\p{Lu}` or `\p{Uppercase_Letter}` to match upper case letters.

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to The Fourth Bird's answer which is correct I am explaining what your regex meant and where you made mistake.

> It will be very helpful if someone can help me out with this as i am just a starter in regular expressions.

What you are trying to do with `[^A-Z]{2}\d{5}` is explained as follows:

- `[^A-Z]{2}` matches **anything** other than **Uppercase alphabets** since you are using a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).
- `\d{5}` will match five digits.

For your input `AB17-12345` it will match `7-12345`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S3YZo8/1/)**

It won't match AA12345, BC12323 and so on.

Matching possibilities are numerous such as `aa11234, $412345, @#12323` and so on.

Comment: I don't this is correct: "Your matches will be AA12345, BC12323 and so on." because of the `[^A-Z]`.

Comment: Oddly enough `AB17-12345` **will** match `/[^A-Z]{2}\d{5}/` because the 2 characters before the 5 digits *are not uppercase letters*.

Comment: @mickmackusa: I offered explanation to OP's regex. Could you please point out what's inaccurate about it ?

Comment: See glennjackman's comment.  You are not explaining the pattern in relation to the OP's sample input strings, you are explaining using your own input strings -- this is less valuable to the OP and future readers.

Comment: @mickmackusa: I have explained what OP did wrong with his regex. As correct answer is provided by The fourth bird I saved myself from duplicating it.

Comment: Look, I'm not picking a fight here.  If you are going to bother posting something to expand on the explanation of another poster's answer,  I recommend that you actually reference the OP's sample input string format.  See what glenn was talking about?  I'm going to bed.  Don't bother replying, do whatever you wish.